# pandas: Dataframe.replace() with regex

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, floating-point

I have a table which looks like this:

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = pd.Series(['1.00','-1']), B = pd.Series(['1.0','-45.00','-'])))

    A       B
0   1.00    1.0
1   -1      -45.00
2   NaN     -
```

I would like to replace '-' to '0.00' using dataframe.replace() but it struggles because of the negative values, '-1', '-45.00'.

How can I ignore the negative values and replace only '-' to '0.00' ?

my code:

```
df_raw = df_raw.replace(['-','\*'], ['0.00','0.00'], regex=True).astype(np.float64)
```

error code:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.0045.00
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your regex is matching on all `-` characters:

```
In [48]:
df_raw.replace(['-','\*'], ['0.00','0.00'], regex=True)

Out[48]:
       A          B
0   1.00        1.0
1  0.001  0.0045.00
2    NaN       0.00
```

If you put additional boundaries so that it only matches that single character with a termination then it works as expected:

```
In [47]:
df_raw.replace(['^-$'], ['0.00'], regex=True)

Out[47]:
      A       B
0  1.00     1.0
1    -1  -45.00
2   NaN    0.00
```

Here `^` means start of string and `$` means end of string so it will only match on that single character.

Or you can just use `replace` which will only match on exact matches:

```
In [29]:

df_raw.replace('-',0)
Out[29]:
      A       B
0  1.00     1.0
1    -1  -45.00
2   NaN       0
```