# How would I change/remove 'non-printable' characters e.g Â from df.columns values incorporating the regex statements already in place

Tags: python, non-printing-characters

Have tried the above with no success. Note ..This is specific to the text Column Headings and not the Column Values

df.columns = [x.lower().replace(" ","").replace("?","").replace("_","").replace( "Â" , "")   for x in df.columns]

Would have replaced the non-printable character but has failed.

Can anyone help ?

[image: csv export post the suggested solution]

Comment: Usually this means that you have [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) or other corruption in your input, or are reading it incorrectly. A much better fix is to repair the upstream source so that the root cause gets addressed.

Comment: Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201665/3155240), which uses regex to replace text with regex.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please remember that `replace` is case sensitive. Also, when chaining functions, the order is important.

```py
"Â".lower().replace("Â", "") # "â"
"Â".replace("Â", "").lower() # ""
```

If the reason for the matter in question is a Mojibake encoding/decoding issue, you can try this quick fix with [`ftfy`](https://github.com/rspeer/python-ftfy) library.
You can use it in conjunction with the [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function.

```py
import ftfy

def _change_column_name(val):
    # fix mojibake
    val = ftfy.fix_text(val)
    # whatever data processing you need
    return val.replace("Â", "").lower()

df.rename(columns=_change_column_name, inplace=True)
```

@tripleee is right, though. Maybe instead of quick fix you'd want to fix encoding/decoding errors in your source data.

Comment: Unfortunately the hidden character is still present when I export to CSV. What could be the reasons for this ?

Comment: @PeterR, I updated my answer. Does it solve your problem?